# Grub2 BootLoader not loading

Tags: installation, 13.04, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I previously had Ubuntu 12.04. Then I installed Windows on another partition. Since then, the BootLoader did not start showing up when booting, and Windows started up asking me to log in. Then I made a bootable USB with Ubuntu 13.04 but when I booted from the pendrive, just a blank screen came with a message SecureBoot not enabled which disappeared as soon as it came. I searched ubuntu forums and found a similar question. The answer was to edit some lines of boot/grub/grub.cfg . Here is the link  -  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2081912 .

After doing the edits suggested in the above link, the ubuntu installation screen came. I chose to upgrade my 12.04 to 13.04 . After the 13.04 was successfully installed I restarted but the Grub2 BootLoader did not show up and booted into Windows directly. Since then always this has happened. I also verified that 13.04 has been installed by selecting Try Ubuntu and checking the partition on which I installed 13.04. All the folders such as bin,boot,.... etc were present. Can anyone please inform how can I bring back the GRUB2 BootLoader with booting options into Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04 and I possible, set Ubuntu as the default OS to boot after the time-out period ?

My hardware specifications --
Lenevo Ideapad z570 with intel i5 ( 64 bit )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows had over-written the Grub menu. So I used Boot-Repair for re-installing Grub . 
Link - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Source - Thanks to " grahammechanical " on UbuntuForums . 
Link - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2159718#post12717318